# Is pdfkit compatible with grunt-browserify?

Tags: angularjs, browserify, pdfkit, grunt-browserify

Does pdfkit work with grunt-browserify?  I'm attempting to wire pdfkit in with an angular single page app but am getting the following errors during my build process:

```
Running "browserify:dist" (browserify) task 
 TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Used --force, continuing.
 TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Used --force, continuing.
 Fatal error: Callback was already called.
```

Any ideas?  I already have requires for brfs and buffer.

Comment: My problem ended up being self-inflicted. I had a few additional source files in another place that were causing the errors. So pdfkit wasn't the issue after all. I have PDFKit up and running now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the attributes in your package.json are in strings, and that you are passing in a directory name not a file name.